# How can I change all the values for keys in a plist at once to one particular value?

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have a plist with multiple keys. Each of the values for the keys is either "N" or "Y".

I don't have a problem going in one by one and changing the values.  But is there a way to change every value for keys in a plist to one value? It would really shorten my code.

Current code changes one value for one key in a plist like this:

```
NSString *newValue;
newValue = @"Y";

[manufacturerDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithString:newValue] 
                           forKey:manufacturerName];
[manufacturerDictionary writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
[manufacturerDictionary release];
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit of the current code?  Is this for iOS or OS X?

Comment: I will edit my question to show the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I'm assuming your plist contains a single archived NSDictionary as the root object. How about this:

```
NSString *newValue = @"Y";
NSArray *allKeys = [manufacturerDictionary allKeys];
for (NSString *key in allKeys)
{
    [manufacturerDictionary setObject:newValue forKey:key];
}
[manufacturerDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[manufacturerDictionary release];
```

`for (NSString *key in allKeys)` uses fast enumeration to enumerate each key that exists in the dictionary.

Comment: Hi Andrew! I tried your solution which looked like it was going to work to me, but got the following nasty little error:2012-01-03 13:37:12.668 PTD[6821:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFDictionary: 0x7895980> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: That's what I get for quickly writing something in a text editor without testing it! The problem is (was) that you can't change the contents of a mutable object while enumerating its contents. The solution is to pull all its keys out into a separate array first, then enumerate that array.

Comment: Worked like a champ, Andrew! Thank you!! You just saved me from writing hundreds of lines of code! :)